# Avoid primitive data types default value in json mapping using GSON

Tags: java, json, reflection, gson

```
public class Test {

    public int num;
    public String name;
    public String email;

    public Test(){

    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

By using above class structure i generate json using Gson library,which works perfectly fine ,but the problem is i want to avoid primitive data types default value to json mapping.for example

```
Test obj=new Test();
obj.setEmail("abc@abc.com");
obj.setName("Mike");
String json= new Gson().toJson(obj);
```

//output json

```
{"num":0,"name":"Mike","email":"abc@abc.com"}
```

In the output json num is assign 0 which is default value for primitive data type int ,i wants to avoid default primitive data type for int in json mapping.
I want behavior similar to reference types.if i do not assign value to name or email it will not be generated in output json.

```
 Test obj=new Test();
 obj.setName("Mike");
 String json= new Gson().toJson(obj);
```

//output json

```
 {"num":0,"name":"Mike"}
```

How to avoid primitive default value in output json?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code instead ,here I have changed int to Integer and also encapsulated instance variables.

```
private Integer num;
private String name;
private String email;

public Integer getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(Integer num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

Comment: Note: don't forgot additional method (necessary in some complex situations) - in GSON you can define serializer/deserializer for any classes.

Comment: @Mark: another solution is custom serializer/deserializer can be class-defined :
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Answer (score 1):

If your fields have to be primitive, or if you are serializing an object from a class in an external lib, you can use (so you can't change it to a wrapper class) an Exclusion Strategy. In your specified case, that would look like:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    if (f.getDeclaringClass() == Test.class && f.getName().equals("num")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
})
```

You can check other ways to exclude fields from serialization here:
https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization#highlighter_288459

Answer (score 0):

From the [old release docs](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#other-changes-to-be-aware-of) of Google GSON library it did not supported the type adapter for primitive data type. But from [the release document](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-222) it does; so, you can write the custom type adapters for primitive types.

I am using till date latest Google GSON library version 2.8.5. I was writing a custom deserializer for one of my Android application, where there were empty values for some of the fields which were introduced in newer APIs of my application, and field type was numeric (integer / float / double), and GSON threw exception with message "**java.lang.NumberFormatException for empty String**". I was able to handle it with below code snippet:

**Test.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Test {
    @SerializedName("num")
    public int num;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("email")
    public String email;

    //getters and setters
}
```

For the sample JSON `{"num": "", "name": "John Doe", "email":"john.doe@example.com"}` parsing fails with code `new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString, Test.class)`. But writing the custom type adapter for primitive type does the magic here.

**IntegerDeserializer.java**

```
public class IntegerDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfSrc, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String value = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now use the adapter as:

```
new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(int.class, new IntegerDeserializer())
    .create()
    .fromJson(jsonString, Test.class)
```

**Note:** Here `jsonString` is the variable holding serialized json.